# How to change fullcalendar cell color?

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar, cell

I'm trying to change AngularUI's calendar cell color.

But always change event color only.

How to change day cell color?

This is my Angular code for setting events:

```
$scope.events = [
    {className: 'fa fa-shopping-basket', title: 'dashboard', start: new Date(y, m, 1), url: 'http://localhost/view_finance', backgroundColor: '#80d4ff', borderColor: '#80d4ff', textColor: '#0088cc', allDay: true},
    {className: 'fa fa-line-chart', title: 'dashboard 2', start: new Date(y, m, 1), url: 'http://localhost/view_finance/d/dash2', backgroundColor: '#80d4ff', borderColor: '#80d4ff', textColor: '#0088cc', allDay: true},
    {className: 'fa fa-user', title: 'balance', start: new Date(y, m, 1), url: 'http://localhost/view_finance/d/balance', backgroundColor: '#80d4ff', borderColor: '#80d4ff', textColor: '#0088cc', allDay: true},
    {className: 'fa fa-bar-chart', title: 'invoice', start: new Date(y, m, 5), url: 'http://localhost/view_finance/invoice/invoice#!/invoice_view', backgroundColor: '#80d4ff', borderColor: '#80d4ff', textColor: '#0088cc', allDay: true},
    {className: 'fa fa-bar-chart', title: 'documents', start: new Date(y, m, d - 3, 16, 0), url: 'http://localhost/view_finance/files/browse/home', backgroundColor: '#80d4ff', borderColor: '#80d4ff', textColor: '#0088cc', allDay: true},
    {title: 'control side', start: new Date(y, m, d + 4, 16, 0), url: 'http://localhost/view_finance/manage/dashboard', backgroundColor: '#80d4ff', borderColor: '#80d4ff', textColor: '#0088cc', allDay: true},
    {title: 'balance', start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0), end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30), url: 'http://localhost/view_finance/d/balance', backgroundColor: '#80d4ff', borderColor: '#80d4ff', textColor: '#0088cc', allDay: true},
    {title: 'invoice settings', start: new Date(y, m, 28), end: new Date(y, m, 29), url: 'http://localhost/view_finance/invoice/invoice#!/invoice_setting', backgroundColor: '#80d4ff', borderColor: '#80d4ff', textColor: '#0088cc', allDay: true}
];
```

This is my current view

[image]

Comment: Which cell do you want to highlight, all cells or just one specific cell?

Comment: I want to highlight only event cells

Comment: All event cells or just one event cell?

Comment: I modified my question.Please see it.There are blue color highlighted events.I want to color entire event cell with this blue color not only event background.

Comment: Okay and you want to do that only for cells that have events in them. So my answer below is incorrect?

Comment: yes I tried it.Thank you for your effort.

Comment: Updated my answer. it's not as easy as expected because of the way full-calendar generates lots of nested and stacked tables. I mulled on it for a bit though and then that solution came to me, hope it helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I did it and its working

```
$scope.uiConfig = {
    calendar: {
        height: 650,
        editable: true,
        header: {
            left: '',
            center: 'prev title next',
            right: ''
        },
        defaultView: 'month',
        dayRender: function (date, cell) {
                 $r = $scope.getDateInfo(date);
                if($r){
                   cell.css("background-color", "#ccf3ff"); 
                }
                cell.html('<i class="fa fa-line-chart"  ></i>'+$r.amount+'<br/><i class="fa fa-user" ></i>'+$r.users+'<br/><i class="fa fa-shopping-basket" ></i>'+$r.income);
            }

    }
};

$scope.getDateInfo = function(date){
    return {
             amount : 50000,
             users  : 10,
             income : 5000
            } 

}
```

This is my view with hard-coded values

[image]

Comment: Well done. Could you explain how that works? I'm just curious, it could also be useful for anyone reading this. What does `$scope.getDateInfo()` do? - I don't understand the hard-coded `amount`, `users` and `income` property values.

Comment: I'm hard-coded that values for test my code.`$scope.getDateInfo()` values comes with `php array`.I don't want to add events in my task simply I want to add some data to calender cell and that's the way I done it.

Comment: `amount`, `users` and `income` property values are change one day to another day via `php array` and separately linked  to pages.I updated my answer with my view, please check it and if you have any further issues ask it..Thank you for your comment

Comment: Ah I see, excellent job, well done! I've never used full calendar without those events but this could be inspirational for myself and anyone else looking to use it in the future.

Comment: Ahh thank you for your words of encouragement and thank you again for your great effort.

Comment: How to do the same in angular 2 and above versions?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the color in the [Event Source Object](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Source_Object/).

Here is a few example:

```
{
    events: [
        { title: 'Event1', start: '2011-04-04' },
        { title: 'Event2', start: '2011-05-05' }
    ],
    color: 'yellow',   // background color
    textColor: 'black' // text color
}
```

Comment: I modified my question.Please see it.

Comment: How can I add event source to my code,I'm newcomer for angularJS and I haven't any idea how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the **[ui-calendar directive](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar)** (or **[full calendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/)** itself) specifically support **changing the background colour of only those cells that contain events**, so there is nothing "ordinary" you can do to set these. That leaves two options:

- **Extend the functionality of the current directive** by wrapping it inside of your own custom directive. (Perhaps the better practice, but I wouldn't do this, seems overkill for merely styling a couple of DOM elements).
- **Download and modify the Angular-UI directive** and suggest it as a new feature. (I opted for this approach and hope that they support it in the future).

**To Modify the Angular-UI directive:**

The directive will probably be in a file called **calendar.js**. Open that and make the following changes...

Inject the `$timeout` dependency into the `uiCalendar` directive:

```
.directive('uiCalendar', ['uiCalendarConfig', '$timeout',
      function(uiCalendarConfig, $timeout) {
```

Add then add this to the bottom of the `uiCalendar` directive's `link()` function:

```
$timeout(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < scope.eventSources[0].length; i++) {
    var event = scope.eventSources[0][i];
    var eventDate = moment(event.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    var tds = $("td.fc-day[data-date='" + eventDate + "']");
    for (var j = 0; j < tds.length; j++) {
      var td = tds[j];
      $(td).css("background", "#000000");
    };
  };
});
```

**How it works.**

When the Full Calendar is generated it creates `data-date` attributes on the *type* of  cells that you wish to change the background colour of (i.e. The cells marked with the `fc-day` class). The image below shows one row's worth (a week) of those cells.

[image]

Inside the directive (where we have access to the events) we can loop around the events and retrieve their `eventDate` in the "YYYY-MM-DD" format as used by the `data-date` attribute.  We then use that `eventDate` to lookup the corresponding `fc-day` cells (using the [Attribute Equals Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)) and then set their background colour accordingly. The `$timeout` service is needed to ensure that this happens after the DOM has been generated.

**Output**

[image]

Comment: You're most welcome, it's a good question, I enjoyed the challenge!